# ETIMEDOUT during sequelize.sync()

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So about 60% of the time when I start up the server, I get this error.

```
[2014-10-31T00:55:30.763Z] ERROR: main/4588 on vagrant-centos65.vagrantup.com: undefined (err.errorno=ETIMEDOUT, err.code=ETIMEDOUT, err.syscall=connect, err.fatal=true)
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/vagrant/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:346:13)
    at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:326:8)
    at Timer.unrefTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:427:13)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/vagrant/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/vagrant/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/vagrant/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:18)
    at /vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:41:16
    at sequelizeResolver (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/promise.js:32:12)
    at new Promise (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:82:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/promise.js:28:17)
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:23:10)
From previous event:
    at new Promise (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:82:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/promise.js:28:17)
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:23:10)
    at ConnectionManager.$connect (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:200:41)
    at Object.pool.Pooling.Pool.create (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:163:14)
    at createResource (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:261:13)
    at dispense (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:253:9)
    at Object.me.acquire (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:319:5)
From previous event:
    at new Promise (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:82:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/promise.js:28:17)
    at ConnectionManager.getConnection (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:183:10)
    at module.exports.Sequelize.query (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:590:85)
    at module.exports.QueryInterface.createTable (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:151:29)
    at /vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:413:34
From previous event:
    at module.exports.Model.sync (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:408:20)
    at /vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:730:20
Possibly unhandled Error: undefined
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/promise.js:66:18)
From previous event:
    at module.exports.Sequelize.sync (/vagrant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:713:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/server.js:111:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

The other 40% of the time it goes through no problem. This only started happening when I switched to OS X, but it's all running in vagrant so it shouldn't matter. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
So I've narrowed down what the problem is. I'm able to reproduce the error if I busy wait for ~10 seconds anywhere in the code (even at the beginning!), e.g.

```
'use strict';
for (var i = 0; i < 1e10; i+=2){}
var express = require(...
```

So it seems that taking too long to call sequelize.sync() will cause this error. But why?

Comment: One of the things sequelize.sync() does when called is creating tables in the database. I can only assume that your app is either creating a great number of tables or your database is running very very slowly. I think you need to post more of your code to determine what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Sequelize isn't managing to successfully connect to your database and is timing out.

Firstly make sure your database is actually running and that you can connect using the same connection parameters from the vagrant box as your sequelize application. Assuming your running MySQL you can do this by:

```
vagrant ssh
```

Then from the vagrant box

```
mysql -usteven -pstevenspassword -hhostameofserver.com
```

This will at least confirm that the application is able to connect to the db.

Also if your database is running on the same machine as your application you could try connecting via UNIX socket rather than over the network, like this:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {

    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    logging: false,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        socketPath: '/var/run/mysql.sock'
    },
    pool: {
        maxConnections: 5,
        maxIdleTime: 30
    }

});
```